# Why are sine, cosine and tangent the "main" trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

So I know that the main trig functions are sine, cosine and tangent, while cosecant, secant and cotangent are simply known as the "reciporicals", but
wouldn't it make more sense for sine, SECANT and tangent be the main trig functions while COsine, COsecant and COtan be the secondary ones? After all, secant is just the reciprocal of cosine, so everything you can do with cosine you can do with secant.

Comment: My main trig function is $e^{ix}$ ;)

Comment: You’re trying to reason based on English lol. Well a reason why secant isn’t considered as a “main” function is because it is the reciprocal of cosine which has several zeros. Hence secant is not defined everywhere. The main advantage of sine and cosine is that they are defined everywhere (actually on the entire complex plane). Actually we only need one of them since the other is just a phase shift of $\pi/2$ away. But even more conceptually, as mentioned above, everything we need is inside the complex exponential function.

Comment: [“One of the miseries of life is that everybody names everything a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand.”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) — Feynman

Comment: @LL3.14. Not surprizing with such a username ! Cheers :-)

Comment: The *[versed sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine)* or "versin" $\operatorname{versin}\theta = 1 - \cos \theta$, and half of it "haversin" were historically important.  One point was that being always non-negative means that they almost always have a logarithm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. $\sin x$ represent the $y$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle and $\cos x$ represent the $x$-coordinate. This is obviously very convenient. Because of this, complex numbers are very easy to express too ($r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$)).
2. We also have the Law of Sines, the Law of Cosines and the Law of Tangents, but no Law of Cosecants or Law of Secants. Writing all these theorems in terms of $\csc$ and $\sec$ will be super inconvenient.
3. $y=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$ are all continuous functions. Because of this, the study of waves amongst others often involve Sines and Cosines, but not Cosecants or Secants.
4. As @peek-a-boo has rightfully pointed out, "a reason why secant isn’t considered as a “main” function is because it is the reciprocal of cosine which has several zeros. Hence secant is not defined everywhere. The main advantage of sine and cosine is that they are defined everywhere (actually on the entire complex plane). Actually we only need one of them since the other is just a phase shift of $\pi/2$ away. But even more conceptually, as mentioned above, everything we need is inside the complex exponential function."

I am not really sure why $\tan$ is preferred over $\cot$ since they have mostly the same properties. Hopefully someone can come up with an explanation.

Comment: Re the last paragraph: not a really significant reason in my eyes, but if $\theta$ is the angle subtended by a line and the $x$-axis then it’s slope is $\tan\theta$. Also, $\tan$ is defined in a neighborhood of the origin, so it’s convenient for some formulas. But more seriously I think we actually like the $\arctan$ function more, because it’s an analytic function which is strictly increasing and bounded and is just nice overall :)

Comment: @peek-a-boo That's possible. My reason is that $\sin$ is defined as "before" $\cos$, so they just took $\sin/\cos$, maybe?

Comment: I don't see how your point 3 is relevant. All of the trigonometric functions are periodic.

Comment: I think point 2 is more a consequence than a justification that $\cos$, and $\sin$ are the main trigonometric functions. If $\sec$ and $\csc$ were considered the fundamental ones, then high school students would learn the Law of Cosecants ($a\csc A=b\csc B=c\csc C$) and the Law of Secants ($\sec C=\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2-c^2}$). The Law of Secants has the disadvantage of leading to a division by $0$ when $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, while the Law of Cosines generalizes the Pythagorean formula.

Comment: The function $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ is the slope of the radius making an angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis, so it is quite a fundamental function. The question is why it is called *tangent* since it is not directly related to the tangent line of the circle (its slope is $-\cot\theta$)

Comment: @Taladris Let $OA$ and $OB$ be two rays with endpoints at $O$, the center of a unit circle, making an angle $\theta$. Construct a line tangent to the circle where it intersects $OA$. The segment of that tangent line intercepted by $\angle AOB$ has length $\tan\theta$. The tangent function predates coordinate geometry, by the way, so it would not have been named after a slope.

Comment: You know you've written a good question when people start arguing in the comments XD 

Comment: The tangent function is not continuous.